# PHP if statement based on class existing - using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying, probably very poorly, to write an `if` statement to change the php variable being passed into a foreach loop, based on whether a div has a certain class.

my code which isnt really working is

```
<script>

if ($(".howto-one")[0]){
<?php $how_to_slice = array_slice($how_tos_full, 0, 3); ?>
} else {
<?php $how_to_slice = array_slice($how_tos_full, 3, 3); ?>
} 

</script>

<?php foreach($how_to_slice as $how_to) : ?>
```

Any Ideas?!

Comment: check this [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

Answer (score 0):

If your main motto is to change the exact div class name to new then you can use the jquery to change the existing div class name to new one.
Add the following script whrere you're putting js code.

```
<script>
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.howto-one').attr('howto-one','new_class')
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

If you use this code you can use the new_class instead of howto-one, but howto-one will not be removed.
Have a look on it..

Answer (score 0):

The combination you are trying won't work.

You'll need to make string of you PHP array in order to use them inside your JS Function. Therefor use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
<script>
if ($(".howto-one")[0]) {
   var how_to_slice = <?php echo json_encode( array_slice($how_tos_full, 0, 3) ); ?>;
} else {
   var how_to_slice = <?php echo json_encode( array_slice($how_tos_full, 3, 3) ); ?>;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The OP uses `<script>`, therefor I assumed the OP wants the PHP arrays available in his/hers Javascript....

Comment: How he uses the PHP variable is shown right there.  It is not in JS.

Comment: Well, difference in assumption then... I believe that he is trying to use the PHP array inside this Javascript if/else, since `if ($(".howto-one")[0]) {` is Javascript. I'll leave my answer in case the OP is looking for this JS solution. If not, he can use your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your content is generated on the server, before it is sent to the browser.  Javascript is just text content as far as PHP is concerned, so as far as the server is concerned your content could look like this:

```
the quick brown fox
<?php // do stuff ;?>
jumped over
<?php // do more stuff ;?>
the lazy dog
```

Both `do suff` **and** `do more stuff` will always be evaluated.

Javascript is client-side, so the `if/else` test is not evaluated until the content gets to the browser.  And in this case there is nothing for Javascript to actually evaluate, regardless of which case is true - there is no content, JS or otherwise, inside those conditions (the PHP does not echo anything).

So in short you can't do it this way.  You *can* do the opposite, and generate JS depending on PHP code, because that code is generated on the server side.  For example (random example, not intended to match your code or functionality):

```
<?php if ($how_to_slice === true) { ?>
    <script>
        $('.howto-one').show();
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <script>
        $('.howto-one').hide();
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

You probably need to rethink your approach.